# Android - SQLite can't get values of first row

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I'm new to app-developing; I started with an alarm clock where you can add multible alarms everything works fine but when you close the app everything is reset.
So I tried to implement a database which works - more or less.
It stores data, but not correctly.
Everytime I start the app the "first row" is gone.
I think the problem should be may when I insert or update the values.
This is my code:

```
// Datenbank Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Datenbank name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarmDatabase";

// Tabellen name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "alarms";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_HOUR = "hour";
private static final String KEY_MIN = "min";
private static final String KEY_ENABLE = "enable";
private static final String KEY_OPTION = "option";
private static final String KEY_HOWMANY = "howMany";
private static final String KEY_VISCOUNTER = "visCounter";
private static final String KEY_VOLUME = "volume";
private static final String KEY_SOUND = "sound";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_HOUR
        + " INTEGER, " + KEY_MIN + " INTEGER, " + KEY_ENABLE + " INTEGER, "
        + KEY_OPTION + " INTEGER, " + KEY_HOWMANY + " INTGER, "
        + KEY_VISCOUNTER + " INTEGER, " + KEY_VOLUME + " INTEGER, "
        + KEY_SOUND + " TEXT " + ");";

private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "";

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        // Loescht alte Tabelle
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        // Neue Tabelle erzeugen
        this.onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void addAlarm(Entry entry, int x) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_HOUR, entry.getHour(x)); // Gesetzte Stunde
    values.put(KEY_MIN, entry.getMin(x)); // Minute
    values.put(KEY_ENABLE, entry.getEnabledInt(x)); // Enable
    values.put(KEY_OPTION, entry.getSelectedOption(x)); // option
    values.put(KEY_HOWMANY, entry.getHowMany(x)); // Anzahl Shakes/Quizes
    values.put(KEY_VISCOUNTER, entry.getVisCounter()); // VisCounter
    values.put(KEY_SOUND, entry.getSongtitle()); // Songtitle
    values.put(KEY_VOLUME, entry.getVolume()); // Lautstaerke
                                                // speichern

    // Zur Datenbank hinzufuegen
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // datenbank verbindung beenden
}

void updateAlarm(Entry entry, int anzahl) {
    for(int x=0; x<=anzahl; x++){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_HOUR, entry.getHour(x)); // Gesetzte Stunde
    values.put(KEY_MIN, entry.getMin(x)); // Minute
    values.put(KEY_ENABLE, entry.getEnabledInt(x)); // Enable
    values.put(KEY_OPTION, entry.getSelectedOption(x)); // option
    values.put(KEY_HOWMANY, entry.getHowMany(x)); // Anzahl Shakes/Quizes
    values.put(KEY_VISCOUNTER, entry.getVisCounter()); // VisCounter
    values.put(KEY_SOUND, entry.getSongtitle()); // Songtitle
    values.put(KEY_VOLUME, entry.getVolume()); // Lautstaerke
                                                // speichern

    String[] whereArg={""+x};

    // Zeile Aktualisieren
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " =?" , whereArg);// new String[] {
                                                            // String.valueOf(x)
                                                            // }
    db.close(); // datenbank verbindung beenden

    }
}
public void getAllValues(Entry entry) {


    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int x = 0;
             do{

                entry.setHour(cursor.getInt(1), x);
                entry.setMin(cursor.getInt(2), x);
                entry.setEnabledInt(cursor.getInt(3), x);
                entry.setSelectedOption(cursor.getInt(4), x);
                entry.setHowMany(cursor.getInt(5), x);

                x++;

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

}

public void getValues(Entry entry) {


    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        entry.setVisCounter(cursor.getInt(6));
        entry.setVolume(cursor.getInt(7));
        entry.setSongTitle(cursor.getString(8));
    }

}

void deleteAlarm(Entry entry, int x) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] whereArg={""+x+1};
    // zeile loeschen
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?", whereArg);// /new String[] {
                                                    // String.valueOf(x) }
    db.close();
}

}
```

The delete method is wrong, too - but just because I donn't have to deal with it till I fix the main problem, when somebody could find what is the cause of what I described I will be more than thankful...

Comment: `Min` (the opposite of `Max`) is a reserved word in SQLite use `minute`, instead.

Comment: What is `Entry` and how do the setters there work? Your `getAllValues()` loop is setting values on the same entry over and over with different `x`.

Comment: In Entry.class I set an get my values

Comment: In my Entry i get multible Arraylists for (hour,min,...) the x is for the index, so the loop is correct in my eyes. It stops when the end of the Table is arrived.